# how to invoke a function the package which was not be imported in golang

Tags: go

how to invoke a function the package which was not be imported in **golang**

**mypkg.go**

```
package mypkg
import "fmt"
func Test(){
    fmt.Println("test")
}
```

**main.go**

```
package main
func main(){
    // I didn't import the package "mypkg"
    // How to invoke the function named Test() of package "mypkg"
}
```

I need you help,thanks.

Comment: As TheHippo explained you must import the package. But the question remains: Why would you not want to do that? Whats your use case?

Comment: If you don't import the package, it's not compiled and linked into your binary, so it basically does not exist. What are you really trying to do?

Comment: I  plan to wirte an simple web framework(using php before).split the url route to instantiate and invoke specified controller and action.@Danilo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to import the package, there is **no** way arround:

```
package main

import "mypkg"

func main(){
    mypkg.Test()
}
```

Comment: Can i import the package in the runtime?

Comment: No you can't. It maybe could be possible with a later Go version, but for now all packages must be compiled into one file.